# Script not working in Wordpress

Tags: images, javascript

This is the rotation script for images

```
    <script>
var image = new Array ();
image[0] = "http://placehold.it/20";
image[1] = "http://placehold.it/20";
image[2] = "images/banner3.png";
image[3] = "images/banner4.png";

var size = image.length
var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())

$('#banner1').attr('src',image[x]);

    </script>
```

and this is the output to display

```
<img id='banner1'/>
```

Testing it here to see if the script works, and it does http://jsfiddle.net/EpnTH/

but on my website, it's not working.

I am using [Simple Custom CSS and JS](https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/) plugin for the script and img tag placed in the page, the location of my choice, but it's not working.

This code for fixed 1 image is working without issues

```
<a href="https://wordpress.stackexchange.com">
<img src="images/banner3.png"">
</a>
```

I am here looking for any suggestions that could solve this problem.

Comment: Think this is considered off-topic and you should contact the plugin author on their support page.  My understanding questions around a plugin are considered out-of-scope.  If you want to learn what the site is about then you can take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script doesn't work because you're using `$`. When WordPress loads jQuery, it does so using no-conflict mode. This disables the `$`. Replace is with a `jQuery` instead.